# How to deploy zippedfolder.sql.gz.gz on my MYSQL server on my windowsplatform

Tags: mysql, import, backup, phpmyadmin, gzip

How to deploy  zippedfolder.sql.gz.gz (its a backup from an existing database) on my MYSQL server on my windowsplatform?

Extracting it twice throws error 'Archives not found' though the size is not zero

Also, importing it directly via phpmyadmin throws error because the extracted file has linux commands for mysqldump which it doesn't recognize

Answer (score 0):

You may try removing the .gz extension. I've received MySQL files disguised with .gz at the end, and they were not actually in the gzip format.